# Flutter: How can I pass images from one class to another as a type Image without being forced to convert it to a string?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

App starts off with a default image background, user can choose another image from settings page and then that image object is passed on to the main page.

Image type is passed but somehow I feel like I'm being forced to switch between Image type to string of image and still getting errors anyway.

Can someone please advise me if there is a better way of doing this.

> Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Image'

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(image: Image.asset('assets/fresco-headshot.jpg'))); //default image
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.image});
 final Image image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(image: image), //Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Image'. But image type image is passed and expected. Why does it need to be a string?
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.image}) : super(key: key);
final Image image;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SettingsPage()));
              },
              tooltip: 'Grid of tasks',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 0.85,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage(image as String)) ,
                  ),
                  const Positioned(child: Stopwatch()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```